# In Cypress testing framework, how to get the "Content-Length" header?

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, cypress, end-to-end

I have been using Cypress to test my code. And as it turns out, the content-header is no longer present when I run the app on Chrome controlled by Cypress. The response content length is needed for the proper functioning of my software, which uses the values to do some computations. I was wondering if there's some way in which I get content-length for writing my tests. The part of my test code where this occurs is as follows:

```
 cy.get('#setSelectedComponent').click().then(() => {
        cy.contains('Part C').click()
        cy.get('#createInstanceFromAsmTree').click({ force: true })
        cy.get(`[aria-label="Toggle Assembly D"]`).click({ force: true })
        cy.get('#matTreeNode').contains('Part C-1').should('be.visible')
      })
```

The 'cy.contains('Part C').click()' is where a response is received wherein the content-header is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check the Network tab for what request(s) are sent when you click on 'Part C', then spy on those with [cy.intercept()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#docusaurus_skipToContent_fallback) to check the request header.

```js
cy.get('#setSelectedComponent').click()
cy.intercept('url-to-intercept').as('url')
cy.contains('Part C').click()
cy.wait('@url')
  // get the 'Content-Length' header in request
  .its('request.headers["Content-Length"]')
```